# Autodesk Construction Cloud API

Tags: autodesk-forge

According to the autodeskissue.png[autodeskissue.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BdXf.png) is from the ‘https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issue-types-GET/’, as the photo shown there is ‘subtypes’ data in the response, but my response come from ‘my.png’[my.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZKie.png), there is no ‘subtypes’, so I wondering the issue is it still in beta mode, or is it I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To get subtypes, you need to add the query parameters include=subtypes. e.g.

```
    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/issues/v1/projects/:projectId/issue-types?include=subtypes
```